# Can't increase size of icons in Font Awesome

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the Font Awesome plug in for Wordpress to display icons, but I can't increase the size of the icons! I'm not sure what I have missed or done wrong?

I paste this inside the Tiny MCE editor: `<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-camera-retro</p>` But I only get a small icon.

Comment: Please show the relevant CSS.

Comment: Hmm, why? Do I have to make changes to the CSS file? I thought I only had to install the plugin an dthe run..?!

Comment: The CSS may be overriding something.

Comment: But I guess the CSS file for from a Wordpress site is to big to publish here!? And I can't use a link because I'm doing the site local

Comment: Do you have any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Ok, if you cant give us anything, how the hell do you expect us to diagnose the problem? If you are worried about someone stealing your code, dont. Someone, somewhere has used font-size before you.

Comment: I look for help somewhere else then

Comment: Probably for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different tag, maybe `<li>` or `<span>` or `<small>`.

- Disable all your plugins (one at a time, or all at once).
- Enable [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in your wp-config.php file.

Does `fa-lg` or `fa-2x` classes work?

One more thing I would recommend - launch up another browser.

- Do you encounter the same problem?

You could also use your same browser, just enable "stealth mode" or "private mode".

- The server could be delayed.
- The cookies could be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

try to put `<i>` inside `<span>` tag

for eg -

```
<p><span style="font-size:20px;"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></span> fa-camera-retro</p>
```

Comment: you can change any css of the icon using style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try example for camera icon

```
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
```

You can replace the "fa-lg" with fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, fa-5x to see how fit it is.